# How is JavaScript's Date().getTime() method implemented?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I would like to determine the wall clock time a JavaScript function is called, with as much accuracy as possible.  When my computer makes a call to JavaScript's `Date().getTime()` function, does it rely on the internal clock of the local/executing machine at all?  If so, what system calls does `getTime()` make?  And if not, how much error is there on average between the system clock and the time computed by `getTime()`?

This StackOverflow question partly addresses my issue but doesn't talk about any possibly latency.  I also require much more precision in the computation: [Is it safe to compare JavaScript's getTime() across different systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342506/is-it-safe-to-compare-javascripts-gettime-across-different-systems)

As a simplifying example, just assume I'm using a Windows machine running Windows 7.

Comment: getTime takes the time from the internal clock of the machine.

Comment: So your only question is about latency? That's impossible to answer definitively and is off–topic here. The language specification ([*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)) does not define implementation in general or accuracy for [*getTime*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.gettime). It's entirely implementation dependent and therefore likely to be different between implementations and platforms.

Comment: Actually `.getTime()` does nothing but access an internal field. The system calls (or whatever the implementation chooses to "*identify the current time*") happen in `new Date()`, `Date()` and `Date.now()`.

Comment: More importantly, what browser (if any) are you executing this in on your Win7 machine?

Comment: If you are looking for accuracy, you should have a look at [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

Comment: @Bergi, Firefox to be specific!  Speaking of which, interesting suggestion.  How does it differ from `Date()`, implementation-wise?

Comment: @Matt: Why not just read [the code](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/jsdate.cpp) yourself? FF is open source! :-D