# Javascript: output current datetime in YYYY/mm/dd hh:m:sec format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to output the current UTC datetime as a string with the following format:
`YYYY/mm/dd hh:m:sec`

How do I achieve that with Javascript?

Comment: By "capture" do you mean that you want to parse a string that is that format into a Date object or that you have a Date object and you want to output it as a string in that format?

Comment: no, I mean I need to do something like var now = new Date(); it does work. But I need to convert it to GMT and format it as specified above

Comment: Please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489581/getting-the-current-gmt-world-time

Comment: holly......that's a lot of work. what about toGMTString()? Not good?

Comment: @sarsnake JavaScript Dates only know local and UTC, not GMT -- [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString).

Comment: oh gotcha. I think I need UTC

Comment: @Jonathan You can figure out GMT time by using getTimezoneOffset() and compensating...

Comment: @JohnStrickler That'll result in UTC as well. But, my point was that JavaScript/ECMAScript Dates simply don't recognize it as GMT, which is why [`toGMTString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString) has been deprecated. From 15.9.1.1 of [ECMA-262](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php), edition 3 or 5 -- *Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can build it manually:

```
var m = new Date();
var dateString = m.getUTCFullYear() +"/"+ (m.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ m.getUTCDate() + " " + m.getUTCHours() + ":" + m.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + m.getUTCSeconds();
```

and to force two digits on the values that require it, you can use something like this:

```
("0000" + 5).slice(-2)
```

Which would look like this:

```js
var m = new Date();
var dateString =
    m.getUTCFullYear() + "/" +
    ("0" + (m.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" +
    ("0" + m.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + " " +
    ("0" + m.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
    ("0" + m.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
    ("0" + m.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: `getUTCMonth` returns values in the range 0 - 11, so you'll want to add one before you convert to string.

Comment: @dgvid gah! I always forget that!  Thank you very much!

Comment: This is quite ugly. Necessary, but ugly.

Comment: @RossPatterson—the Date object is mostly a copy of the Java date object of the same era (even down to the 2 digit year for *getYear*), so blame them. Days of the week are zero indexed too, as are hours, minutes and seconds. Why should months be different? ;-)

Comment: @RobG So we've got that going for us, which is nice.  Now where did I put that quote about foolish consistency and hobgoblins?  It must be around here someplace! :-)

Answer (score 63):

### No library, one line, properly padded

```
const str = (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, "/").replace("T", " ");
```

It uses the built-in function `Date.toISOString()`, chops off the ms, replaces the hyphens with slashes, and replaces the T with a space to go from say `'2019-01-05T09:01:07.123'` to `'2019/01/05 09:01:07'`.

### Local time instead of UTC

```
const now = new Date();
const offsetMs = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
const dateLocal = new Date(now.getTime() - offsetMs);
const str = dateLocal.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, "/").replace("T", " ");
```

Comment: Very well laid out explanation. Thank you.

Comment: The variation in the amount of bs of some solutions compared to others is kinda astonishing. This one cuts through all the bs.

Answer (score 15):

With jQuery date format  :

```
$.format.date(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss');
```

https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple library for manipulating the JavaScript date object. You can try this:

```
var dateString = timeSolver.getString(new Date(), "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")
```

Library here:
https://github.com/sean1093/timeSolver

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but something like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var str = now.getUTCFullYear().toString() + "/" +
          (now.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString() +
          "/" + now.getUTCDate() + " " + now.getUTCHours() +
          ":" + now.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + now.getUTCSeconds();
```

Of course, you'll need to pad the hours, minutes, and seconds to two digits or you'll sometimes get weird looking times like "2011/12/2 19:2:8."

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to answer of @JosephMarikle
If you do not want to figth against timezone UTC etc:

```
var dateString =
        ("0" + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + "/" +
        ("0" + (date.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" +
        date.getUTCFullYear() + " " +
        //return HH:MM:SS with localtime without surprises
        date.toLocaleTimeString()
    console.log(fechaHoraActualCadena);
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting another script solution [DateX](https://github.com/foo123/DateX) (author)
for anyone interested

DateX does NOT wrap the original `Date` object, but instead offers an identical interface with additional methods to format, localise, parse, diff and validate dates easily. So one can just do `new DateX(..)` instead of `new Date(..)` or use the lib as date utilities or even as wrapper or replacement around `Date` class.

The date format used is identical to [php date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

[c-like format](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) is also supported (although not fully)

for the example posted (`YYYY/mm/dd hh:m:sec`) the format to use would be `Y/m/d H:i:s` eg

```
var formatted_date = new DateX().format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

or

```
var formatted_now_date_gmt = new DateX(DateX.UTC()).format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
export function getDateTime(date, locale) {
  const dateTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
    weekday: "long",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    year: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric",
    hour12: false, // 24-hour format
  }).format(new Date(date));
  return dateTime;
}

getDateTime('2024-01-28T22:28:37.659Z', 'en')

// Output: Monday, Jan 29, 2024, 04:28:37
```