# Formatting a date from Date.parse(dateString) in another format

Tags: javascript, date

Currently I am making a rest call to SharePoint using JavaScript Rest API. I am getting a Modified date which comes in the following format `"2016-08-27T17:40:09Z"`, from what I have been reading this is a problem many developers have a problem with.

So I decided to go ahead and use the Date.parse(dateString) method to convert the quirky date format and now I am getting `Sat Aug 27 2016 13:40:09 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`.

Now this is something that can be understood, however I am not looking for this, I am looking for the following format `Month\Date\Year Hour:Minute`. I have been reading the documentation but I am not found anything yet.

Comment: Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: This question seems to be asked fairly regular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362952/javascript-date-output-formatting
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object

Comment: Using back slashes for the date separator is unusual, more common is forward slash: m/d/y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var d = new Date('2016-08-27T17:40:09Z'),
    dFormatted = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()].join('\\') + ' ' + [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes()].join(':');

console.log(dFormatted);
```

Comment: you are right, so your answer is corrected however I went with another method.

Answer (score 0):

If your format is very unique then you need to make your own formatter:

```js
function toMyFormat(time) {
  var d = new Date(time);
  return d.getMonth() + '\\' + d.getDate() + '\\' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes();
}
console.log(toMyFormat('2016-08-27T17:40:09Z'));
```

You may however be lucky enough to find a [localeString format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) that suits you:

```js
var d = new Date('2016-08-27T17:40:09Z');

console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-US'));
console.log(d.toLocaleString('da-DK'));
console.log(d.toLocaleString('de-GE'));
```

Comment: Great thank you I was lucky enough, very appreciated.

Comment: @EasyE the `d.getMonth()` returns the month (from 0-11), so this answer is wrong.. Check my solution

Comment: *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent so will return different results in different browsers (not to mention that `en-US` is not a "locale", it's a language). The above depends on support for the ECMA-402 internationalisation API, which is not supported by all browsers in use.