# How to change date format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date-format

Apologies if duplicate

I have a date in `Mon May 29 2017 12:36:49 GMT+0000` and I want to convert it into `2017-05-01T19:04:18Z` How can i do that using JavaScript.

Here is my code

```
var targetDate = new Date();
 targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() - 5);
 console.log("targetDate is "+targetDate);
```

I am getting output like `targetDate is Mon May 29 2017 12:36:49 GMT+0000`
but I want it in `2017-05-01T19:04:18Z` format

Any help appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at .toLocaleString and other methods of the Date.prototype

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Date output formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362952/javascript-date-output-formatting). Just to make it clear: **JS only outputs dates in full string format**. Next time google.

Comment: There are [*many similar questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+change+date+format), the simplest solution is to parse to a Date and use [*toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring). For parsing, see [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) or [*moment.js*](https://momentjs.com).

Comment: Glad to see some attention finally being paid to date formatting! SO needs more questions on this topic. By the way, what is the rule for transforming May 29th into May 1st?

Comment: Take care to correctly spell JavaScript to avoid search collision with Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best practice, but still putting it here for your reference:

```
Date.prototype.toString = function() {
    return `${this.getFullYear()}-${this.getMonth() + 1}-${this.getDate()}T${this.getHours()}:${this.getMinutes()}:${this.getSeconds()}`;
}

d = new Date()
2017-6-3T18:39:34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

var targetDate = new Date(); 
targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() - 5);
var newTime = targetDate.getFullYear()+"-"+addZero(targetDate.getMonth())+"-"+addZero(targetDate.getDate())+" "+addZero(targetDate.getHours())+":"+addZero(targetDate.getMinutes())+":"+addZero(targetDate.getSeconds());
alert(newTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for JSON encoded date?

You can parse that with the JSON serializer:

```
console.log("targetDate is "+ JSON.stringify(targetDate));
```