# OpenTest Doesn't Take a Standard JS Date for the ReadEmailImap function

Tags: javascript, datetime, opentest

I am attempting to pass a value for `sentAfter` to `org.opentest.ReadEmailImap` function that contains a string formatted as `YYYY:MM:DD HH:DD:MM` per [this documentation](https://getopentest.org/reference/generic-keywords.html#reademailimap)

The closest that I have come to this format is `.toISOString()`. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either build the date yourself using the JavaScript API, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8363049/2196067), or you can use a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) (The moment.js file can be included in your test as described [here](https://getopentest.org/docs/scripting-support.html#external-script-files)). The first method is better for a quick and dirty, one time solution. The second is best if you have more advanced date/time logic that you need to execute.