# Is there any date format pattern to display name of the day?

Tags: javascript, date

In some languages (or frameworks) there are format patterns to render the day of week, either full or in three characters, like ddd or dddd for example: `date.format("mm.dd.yyyy, ddd)` -> 05.06.2020, Tue

Is there any equivalent standard in javascript to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: output current datetime in YYYY/mm/dd hh:m:sec format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362952/javascript-output-current-datetime-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmsec-format)

Comment: Yes, take a look at this `new Date().toDateString()`

Comment: @Daan, how it is answers to how to display the name of the day, like Mon or Monday?

Comment: @gorak: I would like to provide format using y and m and d chars, like in many languages, and place the abbreviation other times the full name to the tormatted string

Comment: If there is no way, why not simply answer that? Instead overacting a minus.. Obviously  needs to understand what the *format pattern* means

Comment: the comment: *use Intl.DateTimeFormat see: https://tc39.es/ecma402/#datetimeformat-objects and its weekday property* would be helpful. or just: *see Intl.DateTimeFormat and weekday*

Comment: As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62028196/257182), a new [Temporal object proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) is being developed that will provide much more functionality to ECMAScript dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't get the minus votes. This is a good question. However asked already. There is Intl.DateTimeFormat available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Explained here as well: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

You can also use toISOString(), toLocaleDateString, toDateString etc.

```
new Date(1590486552434).toISOString();
"2020-05-26T09:49:12.434Z"
new Date(1590486552434).toLocaleDateString();
"5/26/2020"
```

and the link example

```
const d = new Date('2010-08-05')
const ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d)
const mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(d)
const da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(d)

console.log(`${da}-${mo}-${ye}`)
```

Comment: "*However asked already*". Yes, so mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Yep this should probably be duplicate.