# How to convert MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SS in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a month and year picker and the selection gives the value as,

`const selectedValue = "10/2020"`

And I need to convert the above one to `2020-10-01T06:00:00`

Date in the above format can be `01` always and time can also be `06:00:00` always..

Is it possible to convert `"10/2020"` to `2020-10-01T06:00:00` using date format?

I have searched a lot regarding date function/methods but I couldn't find a method to achieve the above conversion. How to achieve the above type of date conversion?

Comment: Do you want to create a Date object, or just a string?

Comment: @Teemu, I am in the need to create it as a Date object..

Comment: Then just use `Date` constructor: `src = selectedValue.split('/'); dte = new Date(+src[1], +src[0] - 1, 1, 6, 0, 0);`.

Comment: [Convert the string to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript) then [output that date as the string format you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362952/javascript-output-current-datetime-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmsec-format)

Comment: @Teemu, Thanks for your help.. But this gives the result as ```Thu Oct 01 2020 06:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)``` But I am in the need of ```2020-10-01T06:00:00``` format..

Comment: ??? That's the date object you wanted ... If you need an ISO string, then just read the date as an ISO string.

Comment: @Teemu, I need to send the date value back to db in the format ```2020-10-01T06:00:00``` and **not** in this ```Thu Oct 01 2020 06:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)``` format..

Comment: You said you want a Date object, that is the date object. How it can be stringified in different ways you can find at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and specifically https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString , note the UTC time in ISO string, though.

Comment: Or if you actually don't need the Date object, make a simple template (`'YYYY-MM-01T06:00:00'`), and replace the year and the month with the values you're getting by splitting like in my second comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the month and year and format it appropriately when submitting to backend as string:

```
const selectedValue = "10/2020";
const [month, year] = selectedValue.split('/');
const result = `${year}-${month}-01T06:00:00`;   // "2020-10-01T06:00:00"
```

```js
const selectedValue = "10/2020";
const [month, year] = selectedValue.split('/');
const result = `${year}-${month}-01T06:00:00`;
console.log({ result });
```