# Format Luxon date to ISO8601 basic format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetime-format, luxon

I'm using Luxon to format a DateTime, and I need to it to be the following format, including the 'T' and 'Z' characters:

```
20150830T123600Z
```

I've tried to format the DateTime using:

```
let dateTimeNow = DateTime.now();
let formattedDateTime = dateTimeNow.toFormat('yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ');
```

But I get the format:

```
2021-05-25T12:43:37.043Z
```

How do I remove the '-', ':' and '.' symbols?

Comment: [related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8362952/10197418) - the OP there asks for a different format, but you should be able to adjust the solution to your needs.

Comment: @MrFuppes not quite what I'm looking for but could work. It's a bit hacky though.

Comment: Without Luxon: `new Date().toISOString().replace(/(\.\d{3})|\W/g,'')`.

Answer (score 2):

You may escape strings using single quotes (Doc: [Escaping](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/formatting.html#escaping)), so you can use `toFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'")`.

Please note that the `Z` at the ends stands for UTC+0 offset, so I suggest to do not use it to represent local times with different offset.

Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
let dateTimeNow = DateTime.utc();
let formattedDateTime = dateTimeNow.toFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
console.log(formattedDateTime)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.26.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of composing the format, you can also use basic ISO format:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
let dateTimeNow = DateTime.now().toUTC().startOf('second');
console.log(dateTimeNow.toISO({ format: 'basic', suppressMilliseconds: true }))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.2.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```