# Javascript daily countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

I want to have a continuous daily countdown where the plan will have 2 schedule/specific time daily.

I am now still troubleshoot at 1 specific time.

The following is modification from this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/23512971/20903104](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function executeAction (target){
          console.log(target);
          //next schedule
      };

      var date;
      var remaining = document.getElementById("remaining");
      var schedule1 = document.getElementById("schedule1").value.split(":");
      var target = schedule1[0];
      setInterval(function () {
        date = new Date();
        var currenthours = date.getHours();
        var hours;
        var minutes;
        var secondes;
        if (currenthours != target) {
          if (currenthours < target) hours = target - 1 - currenthours;
          else hours = target + (24 - currenthours);
          minutes = 60 - date.getMinutes();
          secondes = 60 - date.getSeconds();
          remaining.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + secondes;
        } else {
            remaining.innerHTML = "LIVE NOW";
            executeAction(target);
            //continue to next schedule
        };
      }, 1000);
    </script>
```

1. Let say, now is 11:00 (AM) the next schedule is 10:00 (AM) the output is:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDUuI.png)
   it should be 23:00:00 and counting down
2. I want to add second (or third schedule) and add this code :

```
    <input type="time" id="schedule1" value="10:00:00" readonly />
    <div id="remaining"></div>
    <input type="time" id="schedule2" value="22:00:00" readonly />
    <div id="remaining2"></div>
```

How to proceed to next schedule continuously?
complete code : https://jsfiddle.net/kuraba/6or71L90/14/

Comment: Add `step=1` to the `<input type="time">` to allow modification of the seconds.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher it expands more feature. But yet to solve this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDUuI.png